# Forcing an element to re-render after ng-if change

Tags: angularjs

I'm rendering an element based on the value of ng-if:

```
 <div ng-if="!isUserFollowing">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:40px; margin-top:15px;position:relative;z-index:1;" onclick="angular.element(this).scope().followRelease()">
            <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> Follow Release
        </button>
    </div>
```

Changing the boolean on its own does not re-render the element, but it does if I use $scope.$apply(). While my setup works for now, I'm not entirely sure if it's a good practice to call $scope.$apply() to force my element to re-render. What are my alternatives?

Here's my example usage:

$scope.isUserFollowing = result;
$scope.$apply();

Answer (score 0):

You **need** to call `$scope.$apply()` when the action/event that changed the variable `$scope.isUserFollowing` is called/triggered with methods that are not proper of AngularJS.

For example if you do something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $timeout
  ) {
    $scope.firstResult = 10;
    $scope.secondResult = 100;

    setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.firstResult = 20;
    }, 2000);

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.secondResult = 200;
    }, 1000);

  });;


angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{firstResult}} {{secondResult}}
</body>
```

You'll see that after 1s the value `$scope.secondResult` will change but after 2s the value of `$scope.firstResult` will not change. That's because setTimeout is not `handled` by AngularJS while `$timeout` is. To make it work you can simply add `$scope.$apply()` in the `setTimeout`.

You should always be careful and try to use constructs that are from angular (i.e. ng-click instead of click) because those actions are managed by angular and are included in the digest cycle of the MVC model and so if the Model changes the View and the Controller are updated accordingly.